# Generic interface implementing multiple generic types - how to share a method implementation?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

Let's say I have the following interface

```
public interface IFilter<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> ApplyFilter(IEnumerable<T> list);
}
```

And a specific implementation like this:

```
public class PetFilter: IFilter<Dog>, IFilter<Cat>
{
    public IEnumerable<Dog> ApplyFilter(IEnumerable<Dog> list)
    {
         return ApplyFilter<Dog>(list);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Cat> ApplyFilter(IEnumerable<Cat> list)
    {
         return ApplyFilter<Cat>(list);
    }

    private IEnumerable<T> ApplyFilter<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
         // do the work here
    }
}
```

Is there any way to avoid having to implement separate methods for both Dog and Cat, given that they share the same implementation?

Comment: Do Cat and Dog both inherit from a common base which defines all the values you want to filter on?

Comment: Not a good idea.  Very illustrative how you instantly created a bug in this snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.  When you're using generics without any constraints the compiler would have no way of knowing of how to operate on the different classes (even if they were somehow related).  Think for example how would the compiler know that ApplyFilter would work on both the Cat and the Dog classes? To it Dog and Cat are completely separate things.

However considering that both of your classes inherit from the same base class you can then operate on them through their common base class (or interface), but your PetFilter class would need to be generic as well.

```
public abstract class Pet
{
}

public class Dog : Pet
{
}

public class Cat : Pet
{

}
```

Below is a generic PetFilter class, it inherits IFilter, and even though IFilter doesn't have a generic constraint, you can add one to the PetFilter class.

```
public class PetFilter<T> : IFilter<T> where T : Pet
{
    public IEnumerable<T> ApplyFilter(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I can't make PetFilter generic, so I think the answer is probably no. Thanks for the thorough answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, given that `Dog` and `Cat` both inherit from a common base class or implement a common interface like e.g. `IAnimal`. Then for instance:

```
private IEnumerable<T> ApplyFilter(IEnumerable<T> list)
where T:IAnimal
{
     // do the work here
}
```

In other words, if `Cat` and `Dog` share the filtering logic, it surely refers to a common base.